# Different app add on home screen on Progressive Web App

Tags: laravel, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a vue cli project where backend with laravel api. When an user login at their portal shown a button where they add an web app(pwa) on home screen.
But now added portal to home screen. Is it possible to add different app(pwa) on home screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

via `vue cli` you can add pwa support

Run `vue add pwa`  ref link https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html#example-configuration

Comment: allready pwa added on vue project. But i want to different page from my portal on pwa. Now i get my portal as pwa.

Comment: @omorfaruk what is your question then .?

Comment: I want different page shown on my app from my portal.

Comment: @omorfaruk work on mobile view design that will effect pwa desgin

Comment: Is it not possible to effect different pwa design on mobile view design?